# How to write .json file with multiple dictionary in a loop python

Tags: python, json, python-3.6

```
 while True:
        my_dict={}

         b = box.tolist() 
         t = np.array(timestamp).tolist() 
         my_dict["coordinates"] = b
         my_dict["timestamp"]= t
         all_dict.append(my_dict)

  for my_dict in all_dict:    
        with open("co.json", 'a') as fp: 
        json.dump(my_dict,fp)
```

Output needs to be as json format, but it is not like this `{ {},{},{} }`, it has just dump as `{}{}{}` without comma separator and without outer `{}`

Answer (score 2):

that's because you're dumping each sub-directory as if it was separate single dictionaries. So it doesn't write the wrapping braces nor the commas.

Instead, don't loop on the sub-dicts, just dump the whole list of dicts (adding `indent` parameter allows to "prettyprint" the dump if needed):

```
with open("co.json", 'w') as fp:  
    json.dump(all_dict,fp,indent=2)
```

(you don't need append mode either now, just open for writing/truncating)
Note that you won't get a "dict" of dicts but a *list* of dicts as a result: like `[ {a:b}, {c:d} ]`, which is also valid json.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("coordinates.json", 'w') as fp: 
    fp.write('{')
    for my_dict in all_dict:
        if (my_dict!=all_dict[-1]):
            #fp.write('"key":'+json.dumps(my_dict)+',\n')
        else:
            fp.write('"key":'+json.dumps(my_dict)) 
    fp.write('}')
```